# join tables issue for member list

Tags: php, sql, join

I have 2 tables I am struggling to join information I think I am overlooking something.

```
users
-----
uid    username   rank_id  reg_date     country

mil_rank
-----
rank_id    rank_title    


Desired output:
---------------

   Username      Rank Title    Reg Date    Country
     john           sgt        today        usa



$sql = "SELECT * users.uid, mil_rank.rank_title ".
    "FROM users, mil_rank ".
    "WHERE users.rank_id = users.rank_title";
```

I would like to select all from both tables if possible

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong output?

Comment: Either remove the `*` or add a comma after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `rank_id` key to tie the two tables together:

```
SELECT users.username, mil_rank.rank_title, users.reg_date, users.country
FROM users, mil_rank
WHERE users.rank_id = mil_rank.rank_id
```

Since the `rank_id` column is present in both tables and you don't want that or the `uid` column in your output you probably also don't want to just select `*`.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are apostrophe `"` and points `.` too. Here's the good syntax

```
  $sql = "SELECT users.uid, mil_rank.rank_title
        FROM users, mil_rank
        WHERE users.rank_id = users.rank_title";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this example

```
SELECT u.uid, u.username, u.rank_id, u.reg_date, u.country, m.rank_id, m.rank_title
FROM users u, mil_rank m
WHERE u.rank_id = m.rank_id
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use a JOIN then this is how you would write that query

```
SELECT u.username, u.reg_date, u.country, m.rank_title
FROM users u
   JOIN mil_rank m ON m.rank_id = u.rank_id
```

If you want this for a specific rank then

```
SELECT u.username, u.reg_date, u.country, m.rank_title
FROM users u
   JOIN mil_rank m ON m.rank_id = u.rank_id
WHERE m.rank_title = 'sgt'
```

In answer to your comment, Yes

```
SELECT u.username, u.reg_date, u.country, m.rank_title
FROM users u
   JOIN mil_rank m ON m.rank_id = u.rank_id
WHERE u.status_id != 1
```

Maybe if you read through a [Basic SQL Tutorial](http://www.sqlcourse.com/) you would be able to do the basic stuff yourself.

Comment: everything displays great as I hoped but is there a way to only list those with a status_id in users the does not equal 1